# Can't move object along certain axis after declring #frame in transform field

Tags: transforms, error

I can't move the torso of a character after declaring #frame, then -frame * 0.3 in the y position field of the transform.
I have tried to move the torso with G and to change to y value.

I don't know what to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can just remove the driver and move the object or you can give your object Delta Transform on top of your driver.

To delete the driver right click the y-location field and select Delete Drivers. This way the #frame Driver won't affect your object anymore.

Delta Transform can be found under in Object Properties under Transform and Delta Transform. This way the Driver still affects your object but you can still transform your object.

[image: Delete Driver. Delta Transform]